# Static image positioned far north gets stretched

Tags: gis, openlayers, geotools, openlayers-6

In our application we have a backend that does some raster processing on a region of a map and sends back an image to the OL-based frontend which inserts the image at the specified extent.

The polygon to process is sent as GeoJSON-coords (EPSG:4326) to the backend which then transforms the polygon to a rectangular projection (EPSG:3035 in this case), does the processing and sends the heatmapped results back to the frontend as a PNG-encoded image, reprojected server-side to EPSG:3857 (to match the projection of our OSM-based background map). The image is then inserted in an ImageLayer using an ImageStatic object, whose extent is computed by the backend (the EPSG:3035-transformed bounding box of the image transformed to EPSG:3857).

This works fine, except for polygons in the far north of Scandinavia. For instance, the image whose extent in EPSG:3857 is [1684632.9133543067,9544855.787615912,2902401.684702249,10831736.048522325] is visualized the following way when added to the map:

[image: Erroneously projected image]

The desirable result is for the image to follow the south-eastern boundaries of the shadowed polygon. Instead it is skewed and stretched out to the north-east.

I would be very grateful for any ideas and pointers as to why this is not working as expected.

Comment: Can you please include the relevant geotools code, and the javascript that adds the map

Comment: If the image is in EPSG:3035 projection it should be defined with that projection and extent and reprojected by OpenLayers similar to the EPSG:27700 image in this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html

Comment: Right now we reproject the image to EPSG:3857 server-side so the extent is specified in EPSG:3857. We used to make use of clientside reprojection but switched to serverside since it appeared more accurate. It would be interesting to see if the above issue reproduces with clientside reprojection though

@IanTurton There is a fair amount of code but I can see if I can try to reproduce a condensed version of the parts that should be relevant.

Comment: most likely problem is that you are using 3857 too far north

Comment: @IanTurton Hmm. Isn't 3857 supposed to be valid up to 85.06°N? And the OSM background map is in 3857-projection and looks "OK" in this region?

Comment: @Mike I tried again now and the results are the same when using client-side reprojection. I am not a trained GIS professional so I may be trying to push the EPSG:3857 too far. Even so, specifics in the coordinate transformation algorithm that I employ on the server perhaps maka a difference. I basically use sth like: 
`ReferencedEnvelope roiEnvelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(params.roi.getEnvelopeInternal(), DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);`

`Envelope targetEnv = roiEnvelope.transform(input.getCoordinateReferenceSystem2D(), false, 1000);` where `params.roi` is a EPSG:4326 JTS geometry.

Comment: Modification to the above, I actually use:
`MathTransform defaultToTarget = CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, input.getCoordinateReferenceSystem2D(), true);
Geometry targetRoi = JTS.transform(params.roi, defaultToTarget);
Envelope targetEnv = JTS.bounds(targetRoi, input.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
`

Comment: After processing I project the result (GridCoverage2D) to the map CRS:
`Envelope dataEnvelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(result.getEnvelope());
CoordinateReferenceSystem mapCRS = CRS.getAuthorityFactory(true).createCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:3857");
MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(result.getGridGeometry().getCoordinateReferenceSystem(), mapCRS);
Envelope targetEnvelope = JTS.transform(dataEnvelope, null, transform, 10000);
GridCoverageRenderer renderer = new GridCoverageRenderer(mapCRS, targetEnvelope, result.getGridGeometry().getGridRange2D(), null);
        ...
`

Comment: Maybe experiment by reprojecting the background to check that the image extent is correct https://codesandbox.io/s/reprojection-image-v6s9j

Comment: @Mike Reprojecting the background would be good for debugging but not a viable route for solving the problem. I can only gather that the problem is that I am trying to reproject too big an area for the latitude and projection (3857) at hand.

I would have hoped that reprojecting using the densified envelope (see code above) would help, but even when using 1e6 points I get the same problem, and also reprojecting the individual coordinates making up the ROI and then computing the extent doesn't make it much better (albeit a litttle).

Comment: The only solution as I see now would be to chop up the result and reproject the tiles individually. It would have been nice if OpenLayers would have reprojected the image in a better way since it should have all the information (after registering EPSG:3035 in proj4), but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Which version are you using? 6.3.0 included some improvements to image reprojection https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.3.0

Comment: @Mike We use 6.2.0 atm, I can give 6.3.0 a try and see if it improves something.

Comment: @Mike Tried OL 6.3.1, same problem. My current plan is to crop the projected area as much as possible to minimize the issue. Otherwise I guess making use of a tiled protocol would help, but it would involve a fair amount of work on the backend side.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by cropping the image to be reprojected as much as possible. The resulting envelope is then much smaller which did away with the distortions. Thanks for hint @Ian!