# Far-north raster projection deformed

Tags: gis, openlayers, raster, geotools

This is sort of a follow-up on [Static image positioned far north gets stretched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994714/static-image-positioned-far-north-gets-stretched)

[image: Image showing deformed raster projection]

We are having problems with rasters located in the upper latitudes (say around 65th latitude). As noted in the above question shrinking the bounding box as much as possible helped but that only gets us so far. I was hoping that a tile-based approach would eliminate the problem. The heatmap above is loaded using 256x256 tiles through a custom WMS backend. We would like the boundaries of the raster to match up with the polygon outline, so the problem is still there. (The background layer is an OSM-tiled WMS layer.)

What is the recommended procedure to handle this potential high-deformation reprojections properly?

The projection above is made using GeoTools' GTRenderer (with ADVANCED_PROJECTION_HANDLING_KEY and ADVANCED_PROJECTION_DENSIFICATION_KEY set to true) with a single raster layer (of EPSG:3035 CRS), reprojected to the map CRS EPSG:3857. I also tried doing the projection client-side in OpenLayers, but the results are the same.

Here is a [link](https://chalmersuniversity.box.com/s/5i6khi6exzkgq2y4rsbihs0tsvrauvfb) to the raster data (LZW-compressed GeoTIFF).

Comment: I am using ADVANCED_PROJECTION_DENSIFICATION_TOLERANCE_KEY=0.1, and I am getting this warning which indicates that something is not right I think:

`10:04:13,055 WARNING [org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection] (default task-8) Possible use of "Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator" projection outside its valid area.
Longitude 2147483287°00.0'W is out of range (±180°).`

Comment: We need to see the actual GeoTools code to be able to help - along with an example input file. It is most likely that there is a mismatch in what projection the data is in and what you (or the code) thinks it is (especially with that error message).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was caused by a somehow off envelope when creating the result raster. It was naively created using the input envelope to a crop operation instead of using the cropped coverage's resulting envelope (which apparently differed the more north some of the envelope's coordinates were located).